# What is the benefit of having two subnets, public and private, in a VPC, vs not having a public IP in a public subnet?

Tags: subnet, amazon-vpc

Scenario 2 of the VPC guide on AWS ([here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html)) shows how to set up a public and private subnet. To quote:

> We recommend this scenario if you want to run a public-facing web
>   application, while maintaining back-end servers that aren't publicly
>   accessible. A common example is a multi-tier website, with the web
>   servers in a public subnet and the database servers in a private
>   subnet. You can set up security and routing so that the web servers
>   can communicate with the database servers.

It is my understanding that, with how the routing table is set up, all the subnetworks within a VPC can communicate with each other. So if the purpose is security, so as not to allow outside traffic into a back-end server, like a database, why not just have the server on the public subnet, and NOT assign it a public IP? That way, the same functionality is guaranteed: it can't be access from the outside, but can communicate with all the other servers. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Placing a server in a public subnet but w/o a public IP will prevent that node from ever speaking to the outside world -- it won't have a public IP and won't have a route to a NAT gateway.  This includes non-VPC endpointed AWS services or APIs.  It usually ends up that all nodes need some sort of outside access, so placing the node in a private subnet helps with that.

It also prevents someone from accidentally (or intentionally) adding an EIP or security group to a node that takes what was a private node and makes it a public node.